# What does the number with E mean?

Tags: notation

When I do some computation, I get a number as follows. I cannot use this in my further computations as it requires it to be a number and not to have characters in between. How can I expand this number to an actual number?

```
2.725808E8
```

Comment: See the answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138856/white-test-testing-for-heteroscedasticity)

Answer (score 10):

`E` or `e`, from Exponent Notation, is the scientific notation for powers of $10$ and can be replaced with `*10^`. So $$2.725808\mathrm{E}8 = 2.725808\times10^8.$$