# I do not know how to explain how my P value and my F stat do not coincide

Tags: anova

I am having trouble with an ANOVA test. I cannot figure out how to explain that I would not reject the null with a P value >.05 but my F stat came out larger than the F crit. Any ideas? I am comparing weekly gas prices.
[image]

Comment: 9.8E-53 = 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000098 which is a lot less than 0.05.

Comment: The p-value is in *scientific notation*. Here is a previous SE [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138856/what-does-the-notation-like-8-6e-28-mean-what-is-the-e-for) explaining how to read it.

Comment: So scientific notation means a very small number can be specified with very high precision (many digits after the decimal point). Do you need that much precision? Small p-values are often reported as *<0.0001*, say.