# is my p-value significant at 3.9e-11?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, p-value

I know that if it says < 3.9e-11 it is significant because it is less than. But this time it has no < symbol, just the value of 3.9-11. Does this mean its not less than or is it still significant? does it need to have the < symbol for it to be less than 0.05? I know that the symbol e means that its very small but i just wanted to know that even though its small it doesn't have the < symbol at the start which i thought they had always when smaller than 0.05.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Does this answer your question? [What does the notation like 8.6e-28 mean? What is the 'e' for?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138856/what-does-the-notation-like-8-6e-28-mean-what-is-the-e-for)

Comment: Reading the edit, the `3.9e-11` is equal to $0.000000000039$, agreed?

Comment: no it doesnt, my question isnt about the symbol e and what it means, its about whether the < symbol being present at the start change anything in whether its significant or not

Comment: Is `3.9e-11` equal to $0.000000000039?$

Comment: yes but why does it sometimes have the < symbol and sometimes not? is there a reason for that?

Comment: I don't know why your software works the way it does, but you should ot have to rely on the software to print the `<` to know that a p-value of `3.9e-11` is less than $0.05$.